# vuetify jest button trigger does not work even with spy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vuetify.js

starting to learn how vuejs and jest would work.  watched some videos then started trying it myself but kept on failing with the trigger click.

I have a login button in my component, this is the only v-btn I have inside the  component

```
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn
            block
            :disabled="!valid"
            color="info"
            class="mr-4"
            @click.native="on_login"
        >
          Login
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
```

in my login.spec.js

```
import { mount, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Login from "@/views/Login";
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuetify);


describe('Login.vue', () => {
    it('contain login', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Login);
        expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('login');
    });

    it('login event', async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Login, {
            localVue
        });

        const spy_on_login = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'on_login');

        const button = wrapper.find('.v-btn');

        expect(button.exists()).toBeTruthy();

        await button.trigger('click');  // also tried click.native
        // I even tried using wrapper.vm.nexttick, vue.nexttick but  none worked
        expect(spy_on_login).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I didn't add localVue and Vuetify to start with because Vuetify is actually in the `test/unit/setup.js`

being new with this, I am not sure where to start debugging the reason trigger isn't working as the button does exist

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, advises as I read through few stackoverflow and tried their methods but none worked :(

Answer (score 2):

From `vue-test-utils` documentation:

> `trigger` only works with native DOM events. To emit a custom event, use `wrapper.vm.$emit('myCustomEvent')``

Source: [wrapper#trigger](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#trigger)

Because `v-btn` is a custom component, and may not be a native button element, you should try with `button.vm.$emit('click')`.

Comment: I think you don't need to bind `@click.native` to `v-btn`, try to remove the `native` modifier

Comment: isn't my code above already `await button.trigger('click')` which is without `native`? just I did try both or which part do you mean?

Comment: `trigger` function triggers a native event. For custom vue events, use `vm.$emit`. And I was talking about the listener, which is registered as `@click.native`. Move it to `@click=""` only :)